# For which positive integer $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is the fundamental unit of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$ also a member of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Recentely I've started learning algebraic number theory, so I'm still quite new to the topic. By Dirichlet's Unit Theorem we're guaranteed the existence of such a fundamental unit in this ring. The question is when is this unit of the form $a+b\sqrt{d}$, where $a,b$ are integers. After checking some values in mathematica I failed to notice any nice pattern there, so I've been wondering is there some way to classify all such integers $d$.

Comment: So you are asking when $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)}^\times=\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]^\times$.

Comment: Equivalently, when $x^2+xy+\frac{1-d}4y^2=1$ implies $y$ is even, for integers $x$ and $y$.

Comment: When $d\equiv1\pmod 8$, the equation reduces to $x^2+xy\equiv1\pmod2$, which implies $y$ is even. When $d\equiv5\pmod8$ I believe you can find a solution with $y$ odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $d \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, the fundamental unit always is in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$. If $d \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, this holds if and only if there is a real cubic number field with discriminant $4d$. For proving this result you need to compute ray class groups modulo $2$ in ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{d})$ (and you will need class field theory).